# How to enable disable multiple DOM elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, radio-button

I'm trying to enable many radio buttons using DOM manipulation to avoid click each time on all buttons to enable them.

I try this:

```
document.getElementById("on").disabled = true;
```

and:

```
on-off-btn.off.active.setAttribute("enable", "");
```

Without success. I think I'm doing wrong? My HTML looks like this:

```
    <form>
    <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
    <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
    <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on"> 
    <span>On</span></div>
    <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
    <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on"> 
    <span>Off</span></div></fieldset></div>
    </form>
```

The code is always same about 60 time like this so this is why if I can enable all in one shot would be more simple. I try this using the google dev tool with the console...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, multiple `checkbox` inputs in your HTML can be disabled and enabled via the following DOMElement methods;

```
// To set input disabled 
element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled") 

// To set input enabled
element.removeAttribute("disabled")
```

Combined with `document.querySelectorAll()`, you can achieve what you require as follows:

```js
function disableAll() {

  // Select all inputs with name attribute of value on_off and iterate 
  // applying disabled attribute
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="on_off"]').forEach(element => {

    element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  });
}

function enableAll() {

  // Select all inputs with name attribute of value on_off and iterate 
  // removing disabled attribute (to enable)
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="on_off"]').forEach(element => {

    element.removeAttribute("disabled");
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
      <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
        <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>On</span></div>
      <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
        <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>Off</span></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>

<button onclick="enableAll()">Enable All</button>
<button onclick="disableAll()">Disable All</button>
```

### Update

To achieve the updated toggle behavior mentioned in the comments below, see this:

```js
// Select all radio buttons
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(function(input) {

  // When any radio button is clicked
  input.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // 1. Reset all radio buttons to unchecked state
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
      .forEach(function(reset) {
        reset.checked = false;
      });

    // 2. Create a CSS selector to select all radio buttons that match the .on or .off
    //    parent of the current radio button being clicked
    const selector = (input.parentElement.classList.contains('on') ? '.on' : '.off') +
      ' input[type="radio"]';

    // 3. Select all radio buttons by selector (ie those that match this radio buttons
    //    .on or .off parent), and set to checked
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(function(set) {
      set.checked = true;
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
      <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
        <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>On</span></div>
      <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
        <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>Off</span></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
      <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
        <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>On</span></div>
      <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
        <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>Off</span></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
      <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
        <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>On</span></div>
      <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
        <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>Off</span></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
<form>
  <div class="on-off-wrapper">
    <fieldset class="enabled">
      <div label="On" title="on" class="on-off-btn on active">
        <input type="radio" id="on" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>On</span></div>
      <div label="Off" title="off" class="on-off-btn off">
        <input type="radio" id="off" name="on_off" value="on">
        <span>Off</span></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I try using the google console but it say undefined your code look very clear but it seems Im missing something

Comment: I make a screenshot you can see here how it look https://ibb.co/Rh4c7Bn @dacre-deny

Comment: yes exactly because right now I need to click one by one to enable them this is why I try to acchieve this

Comment: I run you snippet and it work great but I think I miss something since I try on the live site and nothing happen on the console it say "undefined"

Comment: see the new screenshot https://ibb.co/SVGxB37 as you can see I click on one button and nothing happen only the button I click change from off to on don't understand why it's not working

Comment: @Kalipso is it possible to send me a link to the live site, so i can see how you have installed the script?